# Detect child div size changed

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, react-hooks

I have what I like to call "Accordion Inception". My initial accordion will measure its children and set a `max-height` on the `accordionContent`. This CSS property is necessary to keep when [using CSS Transitions on Auto Dimensions](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)

However, if part of the content is another accordion. I'm not able to detect the child has opened up and need to remeasure and set a new `max-height` on the parent accordion.

[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-inception-j3d02)

```
export const AccordionBody = ({ children }) => {
    const { isCollapsed } = useContext(AccordionContext);
    const [bodyCallback, scrollHeight] = useScrollHeightByRef();

    return (
        <div
            ref={bodyCallback}
            id="accordion-body"
            css={accordionBody(isCollapsed, scrollHeight)}
        >
            <div css={accordionContent}> //I need to somehow measure this when it's contents change
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the hook I'm using to measure the bodyHeight

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export function useScrollHeightByRef() {
  const [scrollHeight, setScrollHeight] = useState();

  const ref = useCallback(
    el => {
      if (el) {
        setScrollHeight(el.scrollHeight);
      }
    },
    [setScrollHeight]
  );

  return [ref, scrollHeight];
}
```

I could possibly pass an onChange function into each child but that seems pretty cumbersome. I'm looking for something to detect when the child changes.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need to detect when the width of the body element changes?

Comment: No, I'm looking for when the height of the child accordion changes, it changes when the header is clicked